# Using PI control to eliminate steady state errors

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory

In a negative feedback loop i understand the mistake of canceling unstable poles. But take for example a plant

$G(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}$

and an I-control

$F(s)= \frac{1}{s}$

Then the system has the transfer function

$T(s)= \frac{FG}{1+FG}=\frac{\frac{1}{s}}{(s+1)+\frac{1}{s}}$

My question is:
Is it valid to cancel s=0 poles? so that system becomes

$T(s)= \frac{1}{s^2 +s +1}$

Or does it go against cancelling unstable poles?

Comment: I see only I-Controller.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not ever cancel poles. You will affect observability and/or controllability. Unstable poles are even worse. Bibo stability of a zero depends on its order.
2. I dont see any pole cancellation in your example.
3. In practice you always use PI, never I on its own.